# Default value in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am using Firebase to handle my authentication and other back-end calls for my Android Project (kotlin). Whenever a new user is registered, it can perform one action inside my application for free. The actions normally cost 1 credit.

Inside the users collection I want to set a default value (for column credits) for all new registered users. I could sent this information from my application to firestorm, but I believe this could be reverse engineered letting the user sent a higher default value to the back-end.

Then I was thinking about Cloud Functions. I could create a function that gets triggered whenever a new user is created.

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    // logic here
});
```

But I was wondering if any other solutions are here for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Cloud Function like you mention in your question is a fully valid option.

However, if your functional requirement is that when a user register to your app, his/her user document (under the `users` collection) must have an initial score value that is fixed you could use a [Security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview?authuser=0) as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // ....

    match /users/{userID} {
      allow create: if request.resource.data.score == 5;
      allow update: ...
      allow read: ....
    }
  }
}
```

With the above rule we separate the conditions for creating the doc and the ones for updating and reading an existing doc. See the doc on "[Granular Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#granular_operations)". Therefore we can easily define a constraint on the `score`  **initial** value.

To do that, we use the `request.resource` variable which "contains the future state of the document", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#data_validation

---

You may watch the following official video for more detail, starting at 9min40s: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw